# Android. How to get a list of all my paid apps (only) in PlayStore

Tags: android

I'm interested to know all of my apps that I paid for in PlayStore. There is a easy way to retrieve this list?

Comment: Go to your Google-Play account and click on *My Android apps*.. There you will find a list of all your applications ;)

Comment: Belongs to [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a rooted device you can use Legacy Play Store that you can get over at [Modaco](http://www.modaco.com/topic/356009-r2-legacy-play-store-with-all-purchased-apps-visible/)